# WebDriverException: No command or response codec has been defined. Appium WebDriver not able to find sendkeys

Tags: webdriver

This error is coming
`May 01, 2023 10:29:48 AM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession INFO: Detected dialect: W3C Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: No command or response codec has been defined. Unable to proceed Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:48' System info: host: 'DESKTOP-JAFTAR7', ip: '192.168.1.35', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '11.0.18' Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:148) at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552) at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.execute(AppiumDriver.java:180) at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:323) at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementById(RemoteWebDriver.java:372) at org.openqa.selenium.By$ById.findElement(By.java:188) at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:315) at dogetgopartner.Forgotpasswordbyphone.main(Forgotpasswordbyphone.java:34)`